# c++ no suitable conversion function from "Camera" to "Actor *"

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, reference

Fairly new with c++ so, please be gentle. Getting str8 to the point:

First the actor class:

```
class Actor
{
vec3 location;
vec3 rotation;
}
```

Then the camera class:

```
class Camera: public Actor
{
float fov;
}
```

And finally the controller class:

```
class Controller
{
Actor* pawnActor;
void setPawnActor(Actor* actor);
}
```

Now the problem...

Considering that the camera derives from actor I tried something like...

```
controller.setPawnActor(camera);
```

...but... the compiler says: no suitable conversion function from "Camera" to "Actor *" exists.
Of course I could use: `void setPawnActor(Camera* camera);` but it seems pointless to me to create a function for each possible actor that could become a 'PawnActor'. Any ideas???

Again I'm new to the whole c++ thing so...

Thanks for your time everyone.

Comment: You need to pass a a variable that is a `Camera *` not a `Camera`

Comment: `from "Camera" to "Actor *` Are you passing an object or a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as &camera if camera is just an object as the function is expecting a pointer not a object .

Comment: Thanks for the quick response everyone!

`Camera* myCamera = new Camera();` seem to have solved all my previous problems.